# Limit of the infinite sum of $\frac{n}{2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How should I rewrite the sequence so that we have a form that we can easily calculate the limit?

Comment: $\sum_{a=1}^{\infty}\sum_{b=a}^{\infty}\frac1{2^b}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:**

Start with:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
for $|x|<1$.

Now, differentiate both sides, we get that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
Plug in $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really clever, I didn't know you can differentiate a series like a normal function. Also, is it necessary to find the limit to conclude that it is convergent? Or we can use a simpler method to quickly determine if it is convergent?

Comment: @lsy, it's a closed form solution.